# Solutions of $A^2+A^t=I_n$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

I would like to prove that, if $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies
$$A^2+A^t=I_n$$
then neither 0 nor 1 can be in $Sp(A)$.

Such an $A$ satisfies $A(A-I)(A^2+A-I_n)=0$, hence $Sp(A)\subset \{0;1;a;b\}$, where $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $X^2+X-1$, therefore $A$ can be diagonalised. Moreover, as $AA^t=A^tA$, one can find a common basis of diagonalisation for $A$ and $A^t$. However, I am stuck at that point, that is I can't prove that 0 and 1 are not in $Sp(A)$, even though I can prove that:

•$x$ is a an eigenvector for $A$ for 0 iff $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^t$ for 1

• $x$ is an eigenvector for $A$ for $a$ (resp. $b$) iff $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^t$ for $a$ (resp. $b$)

which give the matrix of $A^t$ in the new basis if one has the matrix of $A$.

Incidentally, once it is proved that 0 and 1 are not eigenvalues, one easily deduces that $A$ is in fact symmetric…

Comment: See my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287415/matrices-such-that-m2mt-i-n-are-invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$x^tAx = (x^tAx)^t = x^tA^tx\,.\tag{1}$$

Now, assume $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and let $x\neq 0$ be an associated eigenvector. 
Then $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^t$ for $0$. Our assumption leads to
$$0\neq x^tx = x^tAx = x^tA^tx = 0\,,$$
which contradicts $(1)$. Therefore, $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

The proof that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ goes analogously.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=QTQ^t$ be the real Schur decomposition, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $T$ is a real block upper triangular matrix, with $1\times1$ or $2\times2$ blocks on the diagonal.

Your condition is equivalent to
$$T^2+T^t=I\,.\tag{1}$$
Since $T^2$ is block upper triangular and $I-T^t$ is block lower triangular, it follows that $T$ is block diagonal. Writing $T=\operatorname{diag}(B_1,\ldots,B_k)$, and inserting it into $(1)$, we obtain that
$$B_i^2+B_i^t=I\,,\quad i=1,\ldots,k\,.$$
That is, each diagonal block also satisfies your condition.

Let $\lambda$ be any real eigenvalue of $A$. Then it is represented by $1\times 1$ block in the Schur decomposition, and consequently satisfies
$$\lambda^2+\lambda=1\,.$$
Therefore, $0$ and $1$ can not be in the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, which is quite elegant. However, my aim was to have a very elementary proof, which wouldn't be based upon a refined result such as Schur Decomposition, so that my students could grasp it… The only things they know are simple results related to eigenvalues and diagonalisation. Moreover, your proof doesn't use the (quite powerful) fact that A is diagonalisable, and I'm quite sure that could be useful…